# find ount what [flush-8:0] is writing

Tags: linux, filesystems, logs, hard-disk, io

Using `iotop`, I found out that [flush-8:0] is doing a lot of hard disk activity, which explains the annoying slowdowns. However, I can't figure out what's the actual cause behind this flushing. No other process seems to be doing inordinate amounts of IO. And you can't `strace` a kernel task.

I've also enabled IO debugging (via `echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/block_dump`), but it gives me block numbers on a JFS filesystem, and I have no idea how to translate those into filenames (just try a web search to see what you get).

I actually have a suspect, a `java` process that seems to cause hard disk activity whenever I interact with it. But `strace -eread,write,open,stat -fp $PID` show very little activity. Are there any other syscalls that could cause problems?

Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried the web search to see what I get and got this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Find_File_that_Owns_a_Given_Block

Comment: For some reason I get negative inode numbers using `jfs_debugfs` (after converting from OS blocks to JFS blocks). In any case this method implies a `find -inum`, which obviously takes forever. I wonder if there's anything else.

Comment: Attach output of diagnostic utilities to your post, please.